# Detect if mongoDB server is master via official C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to detect if a server in a replica set is a master or slave node using the official MongoDB C# driver. I can't seem to find anything corresponding to the isMaster() method (used in the shell) in the driver. Isn't there any way to detect if a server is master from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `MongoServer s`, I believe you can just say

```
s.Instance.IsPrimary
```

or

```
s.Instance.IsSecondary
```

if I'm reading [the API doc](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/800fb23e-aeeb-421a-faa6-d67557a9bede.htm) correctly.

Comment: You suggestions were both null but they led me to the s.Primary and s.Secondaries properties which gave me the hostname, so I'm satisfied. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, got it.  Thank you!  I completely misunderstood the intent of `s.Instance` ... I suppose `s.Instances`, **plural**, for a repl set would give you an array of things to iterate over and ask `IsPrimary` and `IsSecondary` of ... But the `MongoServer` properties you found are clearly much more succinct.